# Error while building Maven mvn clean install

Tags: maven, pom.xml

As I am new to maven build.I have been trying to build my project using mvn clean install .

Am getting error as shown below

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project g-ff: Could not resolve dep
endencies for project com.c:g-ff:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure t
o find com.c:RXTXcomm:jar:2.2 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was
cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the upd
ate interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
n project g-ff: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.c:g-ff:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure  
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDe
pendencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resol
veProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:117)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
    cher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
    a:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
    uncher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
    352)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not res
    olve dependencies for project com.c:g-ff:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: F

    ... 22 more
    Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failure
    to find com.c:RXTXcomm:jar:2.2 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 wa
    s cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the u
    pdate interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDepe
    ndencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:375)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(D
    efaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:183)
    ... 23 more

  [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

   [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :g-fff
```

Could any plz help me to solve this issue?

Regards

DRD

Answer (score -1):

you need to add the artifact: com.c:RXTXcomm:jar:2.2 (groupId: com.c / artifactId: RXTXcomm / version: 2.2) to your local maven repository. It seems that is one of your own artifacts? And not one available in Maven Central. Usually a `mvn clean install` (with not errors) will put it in your local repository.

If that is an artifact is in a company repository try deleting the folder in your local repository that contains that file (or should contain it). There may have been issues and maven will not re-attempt to download it again.

What is weird is the first error has com.c as groupId while the cause is: "com.covidien" - Did you modify that? Because it looks as two artifacts are missing.

Comment: It was a typo .it is com.c.                                        Also I dnt know which is local reposotory ,is the workspce where am building my code and what do u mean by artifact?

Comment: a good start would probably be: http://maven.apache.org/run-maven/index.html - artifact is the file generated by maven or a dependency. It often is a jar file (identified by groupId, artifactId and version). The local maven repository is configured in the settings.xml in your HOME/.m2/settings.xml or the conf/ folder of your maven installation. The default is HOME/.m2/repository - maven will try to find artifacts in your local repository, then look in maven central or a remote repository. mvn clean install on a pom.xml will create the artifact and copy it into your local repository.